# Adding a Fan Button

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to add a "Become a Fan" button to my page or an application? I know there is no FBML code for it, but is there any URL for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can find more info on adding Facebook widgets to your page at http://www.facebook.com/facebook-widgets/index.php.  With regard to the Fan Box, you can find more detailed information at http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fan_Box.